# Serial queries dependent on multiple previous refetchInterval queries

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a polling flow in the app which is a sequence of queries running dependant on previous to finish. Up until I started to use react-query I just used `async/await` and `Promise.all()` to know whether previous requests finished or not.

flow example (before using react-query):

```
setInterval(async () => {
    await Promise.all([query1, query2]);
    await query3();
}, INTERVAL_TIME);
```

With this I got a polling interval which I knew that query3 will run only after query1 && query2 will finish.

Now I'm struggling to get such behaviour using `react-query`. I am aware of the `enabled` param that could be passed to the `useQuery` hook but it is good only for the first run:

```
const {data: data1} = useQuery('query1', query1, { refetchInterval: INTERVAL_TIME });
const {data: data2} = useQuery('query2', query2, { refetchInterval: INTERVAL_TIME });
const {data: data3} = useQuery('query3', query3, { refetchInterval: INTERVAL_TIME , enabled: !!data1 && !!data3})
```

The snippet above gives me the result first interval run is ok, `query3` runs only after I have `data1` and `data2` but in second interval run, because `data1` and `data2` already not falsy it is just sending all queries in parallel, which is not desired result.

It is probably worth to mention the context of the question and the data. `data1` and `data2` are not dependant on each other (could be done in parallel) but should be fetched before `data3` because `data3` is rendered based on parameters from `data1` and `data2`

Can you please advice me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "dependent queries" as documented here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/guides/queries#dependent-queries

This can prevent your third query from running until data1 and data2 are available.